# How is it possible to use RoR for front-end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, frontend

I was reading an article titled *The Secret Behind Twitter's Growth*, and I noticed something that made me a little confused:

The third paragraph which gives some background began with this:
"The popular Web programming language **Ruby on Rails** is responsible for the look and feel of Twitter’s **user interface**..."
Now, I know that RoR is for back-end development, so how is it possible to use it in the user interface aka the “front end”?

link to the article: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/412834/the-secret-behind-twitters-growth/

Answer (score 3):

You can display data from your database in your views.

You can use ERB(embedded ruby) inside of your HTML to display cool ruby coded front end stuff (the current date for example).

You can use all kinds of cool gems like(pagination) which sorts long lists into multiple pages etc.

And also; Ruby On Rails is not just backend, it's a framework where you can use practically any front-end languages/tools(Javascript, Coffeescript, HTML5, CSS, XML, AJAX, Angular.js, React.js, SCSS, LESS, you name the rest)  aswell.

In short; The list is endless, you can do a lot to improve the user experience.

If you are really interested in this exact stuff, you can read the book 'The Ruby On Rails Tutorial' by Michael Hartl where you can build a copy of the Twitter website along with him. Then you will see exactly how Ruby on Rails helps improve the user experience. And you will learn a lot aswell :)

Comment: Great recommendation , so can I combine this with back-end language ----e.g Python- to build a robust and durable website ?

Comment: @yasserahmed No, you use the RoR framework for the back and front ends.

Comment: @ArtOfCode
I see, but forgive me if I'm being a little narrow ... I'm trying to understand how and why twitter had to replace Ruby with Scala in the Back-end while maintainig RoR in the front-end

Comment: @yasserahmed They didn't. The article has actually got it the wrong way round: lots of RoR apps use the Twiiter Bootsrap framework for quick development, which lends a similar look to that of Twitter. The article has assumed wrongly that Twitter is copying RoR apps, rather than the other way around. Twitter uses Scala on the back end, I'm not sure about their front end setup apart from the fact that it uses the same Bootstrap framework.

Comment: @yasserahmed The way twitter works is that, most of the heavy queries are done by Scala. Try to imagine this, they created a web server in scala that when you do a GET request on an imaginary url called `twitter/api/tweets`, the web server will return a JSON. That's how they separate it to ROR, in a page, when a button is clicked, it will try to send a GET request to that url, the JSON response will then be formatted by using Javascript to display it on the page.